# Matlab homework - cell arrays and windows dialogs

Tags: matlab, dialog, cell-array

Program 4: You will use GUI to collect inputs and display outputs in this program. DON’T USE `input()` or `fprintf()`.

1 Using `listdlg()` you will ask the user to choose how many students are enrolled in the class. For simplicity, the list will include only the numbers form 1 till 5. Make sure that the user is only allowed one choice (see Fig. 1). Also consider the case when the user clicks on cancel in any of the two boxes. (You need to display a `msgbox()` saying please make a selection, then the `listdlg()` will appear again).

2 Then you will display the `inputdlg()` (see Fig. 2) as many times as the number of students selected in the `listdlg()` (i.e. if the user selected four students enrolled, then the `inputdlg()` will appear four times to collect the information for each student). Now there are two important constraints here: first, you need to use one `inputdlg()` with a for loop; second, you need to save all the info entered in a CELL ARRAY called Gradebook.

3 Calculate the AVERAGE grade for each student and using a `msgbox()` display the name of the students with the highest average and her/his average grade. (See the example belFig. 3ow). Be careful that the step 4 shouldn’t start till the user click ok on this `msgbox()` first.

4 Then using `questdlg()`, (see Fig. 4) you will ask the user if they want to use the program again or not. If they said yes, then the program will start again, if they said no then the program terminates, if the clicked on cancel then the `msgbox()` from the previous step will reappear.

How can I calculate the average and then displayed with the name of the student?

Thank you in advance! :)

This is what I got:

```
clc
clear
ns = {'One','Two','Three','Four','Five'};
[selection ok] = listdlg('liststring',ns,'selectionmode','single');
while ok == 0
    msgbox('Please make a selection')
    [selection ok] = listdlg('liststring',ns,'selectionmode','single');
end
gradebook = {1,selection};
avematrix = [2,selection];
for d = 1:selection
  sinfo = {'Enter student name','Numerical grade for 1st exam (out of 100):',...
  'Numerical grade for 2nd exam (out of 100):','Numerical grade for 3rd exam (out of 100):'};
  info = inputdlg(sinfo);
  gradebook(1,d) = {info};
  name = info {1}
  a=str2double(info{2});
  b=str2double(info{3});
  c=str2double(info{4});
  average = ((a+b+c)/3);
  avematrix(2,d) = average;
  g = mean(info)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the last line should be `g=mean(cell2mat({info{2:end}}))`

Comment: ok, that will give the mean but, how I relate it with the name, when I have to display the max average with the name of the student in a msgbox.?